# replacing strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

here i need to replace  content "says..." :

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlProductReviews" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatColumns="1">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div>

      <span class="content">says... </span>

    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the data binding tags here:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlProductReviews" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatColumns="1">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div>

      <span class="content"><%# GetContent() %></span>

    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Then in your code behind create a protected method called GetContent()(or you could use a property) in the code behind that returns a string, in your case a string from the resources.  You could also place the code directly in the <%#...%> tags.

Comment: this is inline aspx databinding i think,,so i need to do 
<%# Resources.Default. lblCustomerAction,,rite Dan?
any way let me check

Comment: yes that would work, but don't forget to fully qualify the Resources object with the namespace, or use the imports tag in the markup

Comment: but i think we need to use Getstring() method

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by Getstring(), to you mean ToString()?  Are you receiving an error?